# should the builder reset its build environment after delivering the product

Tags: language-agnostic, builder, design-patterns

I am implementing a builder where in the deliverable is retrieved by calling `Builder::getProduct()` . The director asks various parts to build `Builder::buildPartA()` , `Builder::buildPartB()` etc. in order to completely build the product.
My question is, once the product is delivered by the Builder by calling `Builder::getProduct()`, should it reset its environment (`Builder::partA = NULL;`, `Builder::partB = NULL;`) so that it is ready to build another product? (with same or different configuration?)

I ask this as I am using PHP wherein the objects are by default passed by reference (nope, I don't want to `clone` them, as one of their field is a `Resource`) . However, even if you think from a language agnostic point of view, should the Builder reset its build environment ? If your answer is 'it depends on the case' what use cases would justify reseting the environment (and other way round) ?

For the sake of providing code sample here's my `Builder::gerProcessor()` which shows what I mean by *reseting the environment*

```
/**
 * @see IBuilder::getProessor()
 */
public function getProcessor()
{
    if($this->_processor == NULL) {
        throw new LogicException('Processor not yet built!');
    } else {
        $retval = $this->_processor;
        $this->_product = NULL, $this->_processor = NULL;
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resetting the state in `getProcessor()` is non-obvious and if you want to do that the method should reflect that in it's name, e.g. `getProcessorAndReset()`. A cleaner solution would be to just give the builder a separate `reset()` method.

In general, your `getProcessor()` should not reset it's internal state because methods should not magically change behavior but reliably do the same. `getProcessor()` is a query and that query should return the same configured Processor on each call. It should not change state. Resetting the state is a command. You want to [separate command and query methods](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html).